# How do I filter the "imageformats" plugins that are loaded into my Qt Application by their file extension?

Tags: qt, plugins, deployment

We are developing a framework including a number of EXEs based on Qt libraries.  In order for one of the EXEs to correctly load SVG graphics we need to include an `ImageFormats` sub-directory in our application's main working directory with the `qsvg.dll` plugin.  A problem arises because of the way that our framework's auto-update system works.  It downloads an entirely new set of application, library and other files and saves them with their names plus a `.new` extension.  It then renames the old files with a `.old` extension and completes the upgrade by removing all `.new` extensions from files names, restarting, and deleting files with a `.old` extension during application load.  The problem is that for some reason, Qt doesn't require files in the `ImageFormats` directory to have `.dll` extension names.  This means that during application load the `qsvg.dll.old` file gets loaded by the application and is therefore not deletable.  The quickest way to fix this would seem to be if we could filter the names of `ImageFormats` plugins loaded by Qt, but I can't find a way to do this.  Any ideas?

Comment: Change the folder name to ImageFormats.old instead of changing the dlls names...

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the process of trying that now.  I just thought that it would be easier to restrict plugin loading to only .dll files.  Not sure why they didn't restrict plugins to have correct extensions in the first place.

Comment: Renaming directories solved the problem.